# Avoid duplicate filter definitions when rendering SVGs with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, svg-filters

I am using React to render some SVG elements that include filters. Here is a simplified example:

```js
function ShadowCircle() {
  return (
    <g>
      <defs>
        <filter id="dropShadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%">
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="1" dy="1" />
          <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <circle r="4" cx="50" cy="50" fill="blue" filter="url(#dropShadow)" />
    </g>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <svg width="100" height="100">
    <ShadowCircle />
  </svg>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This works fine as long as I only render a single instance of my `<ShadowCircle />`, otherwise I end up with duplicate filters (and duplicate IDs) in the DOM.

Ideally I would like to be able to:

- Ensure that only one filter is rendered whenever one or more shadow circles are rendered
- Remove the filter when it is not in use

I have tried a custom approach using `createPortal` and the `useEffect` hook, but I faced a couple of problems:

- It is not possible to render SVG Elements without wrapping them in `<svg>` tags, so the portal has to be a `<div>` and all my filters end up in separate `<svg>` documents.
- Calling `getElementById` inside `useEffect` to check whether the filter was already on the page turned out to be unreliable, especially when multiple elements are rendered to the page at the same time.

How can I render one filter whenever needed (by one or more components), and remove it afterwards?